# ¿Cómo puedo desplegar mi aplicación web en apache usando Jenkins?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, centos, jenkins

Tengo que desplegar mi aplicación web ( Que esta echa en React) en Apache2 usando Jenkins.

Quiero que jenkins en lugar de redireccionar los datos del repositorio a "Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/" los redireccione automaticamente a "/var/www/" y ahi construya el build al momento de que se haga un push y asi actualizando el sitio web automaticamente.

Estado buscando por muchas partes y no encuentro información que me pueda ayudar, desconozco si es posible.

Uso Ubuntu como sistema operativo, pero despues desplegare el servidor de Jenkins a CentOS Stream.

Así que información para cualquiera de las dos me puede funcionar.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Y cómo está tu Jenkinsfile ahora mismo? Ve a [edit] y lo añades

Comment: ¿Cual es el comando shell para hacer que se redireccione a la carpeta de apache y no   a la carpeta workspace de Jenkins?

Comment: O ¿Como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías poner el jenkinsfile que estás usando?